# Java: I tried making an array with doubles and a for loop and its not working

Tags: java

I'm getting an error at the array next double portion. When I try the same code but use int instead of double, it works perfectly fine. I know int and double are different but what should I change my code to so that it works?

Int code that works:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[]numbers = new int[3];  
        for (int c=0;c<numbers.length;c++) {
            System.out.println("Enter a number");
            numbers[c] = in.nextInt();
        }
        for(int c=0;c<numbers.length;c++) {
            System.out.println(numbers[c]);
        }
    }
}
```

Double code I changed it to:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MPA1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        double[]numbers = new double[3];    
        for (double c=0;c<numbers.length;c++) {
            System.out.println("Enter a number");
            numbers[c] = in.nextDouble();
        }
        for(double c=0;c<numbers.length;c++) {
            System.out.println(numbers[c]);
        }
    }
}
```

Doubles code (errors underlined):

[image]

Errors:
[image]

I tried finding the fix to my problem online but I'm just getting more confused, any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't get the issue. You said you tried changing `double` to `int`. Then what?

Comment: Then it didn't work. I'll add the Int code as well.

Comment: `for (double c=0;c<numbers.length;c++) {` and then: `numbers[c]` you can't use a double as an array index. It makes no sense. Use ints in the for loop: `for (int c=0; c < numbers.length; c++) {`

Comment: Side note: *don't try to run code that doesn't compile*. You should never get a "unresolved compilation problems" error, and instead should fix the compilation problem at the compilation stage, not at the run stage.

Comment: OMG it works!!!! Thank you so much! And thanks for the advice!